# Spark: coalesce very slow even the output data is very small

Tags: scala, apache-spark, coalesce

I have the following code in Spark:

```
myData.filter(t => t.getMyEnum() == null)
      .map(t => t.toString)
      .saveAsTextFile("myOutput")
```

---

There are 2000+ files in the myOutput folder, but only a few t.getMyEnum() == null, so there are only very few output records. Since I don't want to search just a few outputs in 2000+ output files, I tried to combine the output using coalesce like below:

```
myData.filter(t => t.getMyEnum() == null)
      .map(t => t.toString)
      .coalesce(1, false)
      .saveAsTextFile("myOutput")
```

Then the job becomes EXTREMELY SLOW! I am wondering why it is so slow? There was just a few output records scattering in 2000+ partitions? Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 22):

> if you're doing a drastic coalesce, e.g. to numPartitions = 1, this may result in your computation taking place on fewer nodes than you like (e.g. one node in the case of numPartitions = 1). To avoid this, you can pass shuffle = true. This will add a shuffle step, but means the current upstream partitions will be executed in parallel (per whatever the current partitioning is).
>
> Note: With shuffle = true, you can actually coalesce to a larger
> number of partitions. This is useful if you have a small number of partitions, say 100, potentially with a few partitions being abnormally large. Calling coalesce(1000, shuffle = true) will result in 1000 partitions with the data distributed using a hash partitioner.

So try by passing the true to `coalesce` function. i.e.

```
myData.filter(_.getMyEnum == null)
      .map(_.toString)
      .coalesce(1, shuffle = true)
      .saveAsTextFile("myOutput")
```

Comment: Is `coalesce(1, shuffle = true)` equivalent to `repartition(1)` ?

Comment: Yes, it is the same: if you look at the source code, repartition(1) has shuffle set to true by default.

Comment: Thanks for this. It optimized my 10 minute task to only 1.8