# Speed up Spark write when coalesce = 1?

Tags: apache-spark, parquet

I have a Spark job that reads in a day worth of data from location A and writes out to location B. The point of the job is to concatenate many small files into a single file for each hive style partition in s3. My code is extremely simple but it runs very very slow.

**Code**

```
df = spark.read.parquet('s3://location/A/')

(df
    .coalesce(1)
    .write
    .mode('overwrite')
    .partitionBy('date', 'user_id')
    .parquet('s3://location/B/'))
```

**Spark Submit**

```
spark-submit \
    --master spark://foobar \
    --deploy-mode cluster \
    --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true \
    --conf spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true \
    --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=1 \
    --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=18 \
    --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors=4 \
    --conf spark.executor.memory=4G \
    --conf spark.executor.cores=4 \
    --conf spark.driver.memory=2G \
    --conf spark.shuffle.io.preferDirectBufs=false \
    --conf spark.executor.heartbeatInterval=10000000 \
    --conf spark.network.timeout=10000000
```

What kind of configuration can I do to make it run faster, or is coalesce(1) just always going to be very slow?

Comment: Have you looked at post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31056476/spark-coalesce-very-slow-even-the-output-data-is-very-small?rq=1

Comment: @Explorer I don't think you can do shuffle=True on the DataFrame writers coalesce: http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame

Answer (score 1):

The link posted by @Explorer could be helpful. Try repartition(1) on your dataframes, because it's equivalent to coalesce(1, shuffle=True). 
Be cautious that if your output result is quite large, the job will also be very slow due to the drastic network IO of shuffle.